# R - Filter Dates by Time Window without including weekends

Tags: r, datetime

Is there a way to window filter dates by a number of days excluding weekends?

I know you can use the between function for filtering between two specific dates but I only know one of the two specific dates, with the other date I would like to do is 4 days prior in business days only (not counting weekends).

An pseudo-example of what I am looking for is, given this wednesday I want to filter everything up to 4 business days beforehand:
`window(z, start = as.POSIXct("2017-09-13"), end = as.POSIXct("2017-09-20"))`

Another example would be if I am given this Friday's date, the start date would be Monday.

Ideally, I want to be able to play with the window value.

Comment: Have you looked into zoo for this? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-0/topics/window.zoo

Comment: The chron package has is.weekend and is.holiday. Also see the bizdays package.